# Get List of Elements in Tree with specific Field Value

Tags: vb.net, linq, properties, interface

I have an Interface like this:

```
Public Interface TreeSelectorAttributes
    Property selectedInTreeSelector As Boolean
    Property Name As String
    ReadOnly Property childs As IEnumerable(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
End Interface
```

and I have a TreeView which has a List of this TreeSelectorAttributes:

```
Public Property rootList As IEnumerable(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
```

now after the User chooses which elements he wants to select and which not I want to be able to return a Tree of all selected Elements but this property only returns the first layer of Elements:

```
Public ReadOnly Property checkedList As List(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
    Get
        Return (From ele As TreeSelectorAttributes
                In rootList
                Where ele.selectedInTreeSelector = True).ToList()
    End Get
End Property
```

How can I return also only the selected child Elements in this tree/list?

---

As pointed out in the comments I can't change the childs (ReadOnly)
So my Idea would be to have in the Interface sth like a Property "selectedChilds"

Is that possible?
The problem I see is that in an Interface I cant just implement the Property directly and I don't like the other options I see to do that:
Have an Abstract Class with the implemented Property selectedChilds -> I don't like that because if I would do that every time ...
Implement the Property myself everytime when I implement the Interface -> I don't like that because I will have CodeClones over CodeClones :/

Comment: How deep is the tree, only one level children? You want to return a `List(of TreeSelectorAttributes)` which contains all parents and children on the same level or only the parents where all children's `selectedInTreeSelector` is `true`?

Comment: If you instead want to return only the parent with `childs` only containing `TreeSelectorAttributes` that also have `selectedInTreeSelector=True` that doesn't work because `childs` is `ReadOnly`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know how many child levels there are, I want to have it Generic. In my current use case I have 3 Levels

Comment: @TimSchmelter I did - but I answered by changing the Question ;) Wanted to tell you afterwards over the comments :D
Oh no I didn't... sry. I want them in a Tree not in a List all on the same lvl

Comment: You want them in a tree not in a list? But your property returns a `List(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood it correctly you want to get all selected parents and all selected children. You could use a  recursive method:

```
Public ReadOnly Property checkedList As List(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
    Get
        Return rootList.Where(Function(t) t.SelectedInTreeSelector).
            SelectMany(Function(root) GetSelectedChildren(root)).
            ToList()
    End Get
End Property

Function GetSelectedChildren(root As TreeSelectorAttributes, Optional includeRoot As Boolean = True) As List(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
    Dim allSelected As New List(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
    If includeRoot Then allSelected.Add(root)
    Dim childTrees As New Queue(Of TreeSelectorAttributes)
    childTrees.Enqueue(root)
    While childTrees.Count > 0
        Dim selectedChildren = From c In childTrees.Dequeue().Children
                               Where c.SelectedInTreeSelector
        For Each child In selectedChildren
            allSelected.Add(child)
            childTrees.Enqueue(child)
        Next
    End While
    Return allSelected
End Function
```

This method uses a [`Queue(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7977ey2c(v=vs.100).aspx) to support theoretically infinite depth.